# Unexpected grunt-http error when posting to Atlassian Confluence api

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, confluence, confluence-rest-api

Attempting to create a wiki page on an Atlassian wiki. I previously was using a python script and this code worked no problem:

```
data = json.dumps({"type":"page", "data":"testData", "title":postTitle,"space":{"key":"EB"}, "body":{"storage":{"value": content,"representation":"storage"}}})
r = requests.post("https://estech.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content/", data=data, headers=headers, auth=(confluenceLogin['username'], confluenceLogin['password']))
```

Now I'm trying to use the following grunt task configuration:

```
    http: {
        atlassianwiki: {
            options: {
                uri: atlassianURL + "/wiki/rest/api/content/",
                headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                auth: {
                    "user": confluencelogin,
                    "pass": confluencepass
                },
                method:"POST",
                body: JSON.stringify(wikijson)
            }
        }
    }
```

with wikijson looking like:

```
wikijson = {
            "type": "page",
            "data": "testData",
            "title": "testtitle",
            "space": {key:"EB"},
            "body": {
                "storage": {
                    "value": "<p>testing posting</p>",
                    "representation": "storage"
                }
            }
        }
```

And I get the following error when this task runs:

```
Fatal error: 500 {"statusCode":500, "message":"java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input"}
```

Upon a bit of google-fu, I found that some people claim they fixed this by adding "--post302" to their curl command line. But I don't really know or understand how that applies here.

Answer (score 2):

i was fighting with confluence REST API and in my case the problem was in content-type header, but you seem to have it already.
I didn't try to create new page but to update existing one
Confluence API seemed a little bit magic to me, so i just leave here all steps i had to make before it started working, maybe one of them will help you.

```js
function composeRequest(method) {
  var auth = new Buffer(user + ':' + pass).toString('base64');
  var request = {
  host: 'confluence.myserver.com',
  port: 443,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  'path': path,
  method: method || "GET",
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + auth,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  requestCert: true,
  agent: false
};


  return request;
}
```

And it appeared that page update request JSON MUST contain

- pageId (even it is inside path, you need to repeat it)
- type
- title
- version (it's weird, but you should set it. 0 or 1, i don't remember)

And when your data if filled, you should convert it to string and fill content-type field in your request!

```js
data = JSON.stringify(data);
request.headers['Content-Length'] = data.length;
https.request(request, respondHandler)
```