# Update a page in Confluence using REST API

Tags: jira, confluence, jira-rest-api, confluence-rest-api

This is what I've currently got and it creates a new Confluence page. It doesn't update it. Also it posts it in the root space, `TST`, but I want it to be in `TST/space1/subsection2/updateThisPage`.

```
curl -v -u admin:admin -X POST -H Content-Type: application/json -d  "{\"id\":\"123456\",\"type\":\"page\",\"title\":\"new page\",\"space\":{\"key\":\"TST\",\"title\":\"updateThisPage\"},\"body\":{\"storage\":{\"value\":\"<p>This is the updated text for the new page</p>\",\"representation\":\"storage\"}},\"version\":{\"number\":3}}" http://localhost:8090/rest/api/content?spaceKey=TST&title=updateThisPage
```

This is the error message I get

```
{"statusCode":400,"message":"A page with this title already exists: A page already exists with the title new page in the space with key TST"}
```

Would it be a permissions error? I know I do not have access to delete.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use request /rest/api/content/{id}.

This worked for me.

```
curl -u admin:admin -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"id\":\"26738701\",\"type\":\"page\",\"title\":\"new page\",\"space\":{\"key\":\"RO\"},\"body\":{\"storage\":{\"value\":\"<p>UPDATE This is a new page</p>\",\"representation\":\"storage\"}},\"version\":{\"number\":2}}" http://localost:10080/rest/api/content/26738701
```

JSON Payload:

```
{  
   "id":"26738701",
   "type":"page",
   "title":"new page",
   "space":{  
      "key":"RO"
   },
   "body":{  
      "storage":{  
         "value":"<p>UPDATE This is a new page</p>",
         "representation":"storage"
      }
   },
   "version":{  
      "number":2
   }
}
```

Don't forget to use:

- content ID in data part
- version number in data part
- PUT request
- content ID in request

Comment: Do you know why it moves the page to the root of the hierarchy instead of keeping it where it is?

Comment: @GregWringle, After some trial and error and getting around some annoying quirks, the following worked for me:
Use '?expand=ancestors,space,version' in GET request. You will get a list of objects in the 'ancestors' in the response. Use the *last* object in that list and put it as the *only* object in the list for 'ancestors' in PUT request. Make sure you have all other required parts such as page ID, version number, etc as before. If you copy the entire value (list of objects) of 'ancestors' from GET response into the PUT request, it won't work!

Comment: @iaswtw Thanks!  That works, iaswtw.   Also, I found I don't need the whole ancestor object:  this suffices:

page: { 'id':'2', ... all the other stuff ... ancestors: [ { 'id':'1'} ]

That is:  I only need the ancestor ID, not the huge big thingy =)

Comment: I was missing the "representation"

Answer (score 0):

Try to use PUT instead of POST.

```
curl -v -u admin:admin -X PUT -H Content-Type: application/json -d  "{\"id\":\"123456\",\"type\":\"page\",\"title\":\"new page\",\"space\":{\"key\":\"TST\",\"title\":\"updateThisPage\"},\"body\":{\"storage\":{\"value\":\"<p>This is the updated text for the new page</p>\",\"representation\":\"storage\"}},\"version\":{\"number\":3}}" http://localhost:8090/rest/api/content?spaceKey=TST&title=updateThisPage
```

Comment: That yields {"statusCode":500,"message":"javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: null"}

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for javascript solution, here is my answer to another question like that
[Unexpected grunt-http error when posting to Atlassian Confluence api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744858/unexpected-grunt-http-error-when-posting-to-atlassian-confluence-api/30107677#30107677)

And here you can find working code i've developed on confluence hackathon
https://github.com/devex-web-frontend/dxWebPlugins/blob/master/src/confluence/helpers/buffer.js

Comment: Is there a bash solution, by any chance?